# Clean page urls using URI Routing in Codeigniter

Tags: php, routes, codeigniter-3

Here is my folder structure

```
application
    |
    controllers
              |
              Pages.php
    |
    views
        |
        pages
             about.php
             home.php
```

I want to access my about.php page by just going to **base_url/about** but i keep getting `The requested URL localhost/appfolder/about` was not found on this server.

Here is how my Pages controller looks like

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller{
    public function view($page = 'home'){
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            show_404();
        }
        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

and my routes.php looks like this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: This may help you to understand the concept  https://benoitpasquier.com/dynamic-url-rewriting-codeigniter/    AND https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace`/` by `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` in `file_exists` function. It should work by now.
And in routes.php `default_controller` should be `pages`, not `pages/view`.

Comment: `if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'pages'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.''.$page.'.php')){
    show_404();`  not working

Comment: How about `localhost/appfolder/index.php/about`? If you want to access withough index.php, you need to make some changes in .htaccess